# show details of the file before file upload

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to populate the table dynamically with the filename, filesize and some operations like delete the file once the user selects the file to upload, showing details of the file selected to upload, in a table format after the user selects the file using jsp, javascript.
I have tried the below code, but i'am not sure how to get the file size and perform delete operation without the upload has performed.Whenever user choose the file to upload,a table should generate showing details of the file like file size,file path, name of the file etc before the user submits the form. Please find the similar scenario in http://jsfiddle.net/s98Tw/4/

JSP code:

```
 <table border="1"> <tr>
         <td> <input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" id="file1" onchange="addFileData(this)" multiple /></td>
            </tr>
           </table>

         <table border="1">
             <tr>
                    <th>SNo</th><th>FileName</th><th>FileSize</th><th>Action</th> </tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="text" name="sno" id="sno"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fileSize" id="fileSize"/></td>
                        <td><a href="delete">Delete</a></input></td>
            </tr>

             </table>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function addFileData(field){
   var file_name = document.getElementById("file1").value;
    document.getElementById("fileName").value=file_name;
}
```

Comment: You can't delete files from the client's machine and shouldn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Javascript File type. You can get the File with the Web File API.

```
document.getElementById("file1").onchange = function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = file.size + " bytes";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = file.name;

};
```

Here's a fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/n3zx7/

As for deleting -- You can't delete files from a user's computer. It's prevented by browser security (and lack thereof methods for deleting local files).

You *can*, however, get the path from the file using browser-specific implementations of `*fullPath` eg. `file.mozFullPath` or `file.webkitFullPath`

Comment: this is working in JSFIDLLE but when i kept the same code in my JSP page its not showing the file size and filename, in error console its showing the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined " -@Kodlee Yin .Thanks.

Comment: Remember "this" references the caller of the function. Be sure that you're correctly getting the `"DOM Element Node".files`